# Delete Google Cloud storage bucket object using JSON API

Tags: object, curl, google-cloud-storage, bucket, php-curl

how we can delete google cloud storage object using JSON API and php curl.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $obejct = rawurlencode ($obejct); // $object : object name

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/".BUCKET."/o/".$obejct);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/http";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result
```